# Need a good book and sample application for doing a cloud-web-mobile app using Grails, Html5/JS and Google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, grails, extjs

After years /decades of using tasks managers: Lotus Notes, Outlook, Palm (that was a good one), etc.. and now using [Appigo](http://www.appigo.com/), after using [Toodledo](http://www.toodledo.com/), a friend of mine and me (both programmers) got tired of how far are all those from our personal GTD style and we decided to build one, something that we can customize as much as we can moving forward. We will do it open source open to public.
Appigo and Toodledo a great inspirations from a functional and technological point of view. We like the server on the cloud, the clients on browser and mobile platforms.
We have been thinking this for a while but when we saw Grails and did some of the tutorials, coincidentally on the task manager subject, we said ‘great, we can use this technology to build ours, this sounds cool’. (at least for the web part and the model, the core part).
Following Appigo strategy also, we plan to use Google App Engine for hosting the back-end.
On the mobile side, since we do not have time for hard core objective-c and stuff and we have a decent experience on Javascript frameworks we decided to use the now popular HTML5/Javascript approach and we think we decided for [Sencha](http://www.sencha.com/) but any other Framework may be fine (Dojo, jQuery, etc).

Not surprisingly, our mobile and web clients will communicate with the server primarily using REST and  we plan to have a server-side MVC (Grails) and a client-side MVC (like Sencha or Dojo propose)

We do not want to bother too much about databases, we love the Grails idea of creating a model-driven objects and storage.

Our project will be open source and hosted on github for anybody to use it.

**Ok, here is the actual question:**

Do you guys know good books or sample apps or articles that can help us go through this end-to-end. Of course we could go alone, but we will greatly enjoy going through some books, tutorials first to glue of these things together, decide good patterns to use, learn tips, experiences..etc. We do not have experience with Grails. (but a lot of java and javascript web development), of course I can find books about Grails but we want something end to end, with a good sample focusing on practices and patterns.

Basically a book or article that somehow touches part of this topic **“good practices and experience building something like a task manager that runs on Google cloud platform, has the server side done with Grails and the browser and mobile clients using robust HTML5 javascript frameworks”.**

Can anybody point us into this?

Thanks!

Comment: So, you're looking for a book that will tell you exactly how to implement an application with a very specific set of technologies that you expect to host for free? I feel utterly compelled to help you. I'll have in answer to 10-15 minutes.

Comment: Adam, thanks for the comment. I just did some edits accordingly. You were right about the my abuse of the word 'free'. Regarding the "very specific set of technologies".. I am not so sure I agree. Yes, they are specific, but there are tons of books out there that use specific stacks: LAMP + Javascript, .NET MVC + Jquery,... etc. I think GAE, Grails and a good MVC HTML5/JS framework is a killer stack.

Comment: What the reason of using Grails on GAE?? You can't use GORM here, you don't need GSP (or view layer at all). Why not Gaelyk? Why not Spring MVC?

Comment: Well.. Then you need to wait for Grails in action, second edition. Grails in action 1st edition, teaches you best practices. But it wont teach us how to use HTML5 and Javascript! And Grails in action, second edition has a separate chapter on "cloud platform"..

Comment: Thanks Ant's, I think I am looking forward to that Grails in Action 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done a couple of engines that are build using grails + the google app engine. My experience is that you are going to have to build up the knowledge thought actually doing the work.

It's very easy to start out but once you get about knee deep there are some very interesting problems that can crop up.

Now that being said the main resources that I have found useful are the following:

http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596522735.do

[http://www.amazon.com/Groovy-Action-Dierk-Koenig/dp/1932394842](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1932394842)

http://www.manning.com/gsmith/

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/overview

The link above gives a good java over view. But you will need to be able to distill that down to groovy.

http://www.grails.org/plugin/app-engine

and finally www.google.com

but i found that most of the blogs out there are dated to earlier version of grails. And a lot of the issues they were seeing have been fix in 2.0 or are no longer issues at all.

Comment: Thanks nate_weldom, I really appreciated that list for the grails+google part. I know there are a lot of blogs and resources out there but nothing like a short list done by somebody with experience. Now, we just need to add something to glue the javascript part and probably decide on the framework to use, i am still debating on that. Some days i think i will end up using two jQuery and Sencha.  I found them useful in different scenarios. But still not sure.

Comment: i haven't used Sencha yet, but jQuery and jQuery-ui are by far my favorite JavaScript libraries.....it was a very good thing when they stripped Prototype out of grails 2.0

Comment: Thanks nate again, and you just motivated me to go further on jQuery. I learned Ajax using Dojo when i was at an ibm lab.. and the keep using by inertia, Sencha was a sort of upgrade. Here is my non scientific feeling on these 3 which is consistent with what I have read here in some other posts: jQuery seems to me like an extension to HTML..a sort of CSS for behaviour.. Dojo goes into the MVC OO javascript and gives your both paradigms at the same time, Sencha is just OO and yo do not see HTML anymore. So, it seems to make sense to combine jQuery and Sencha to fine tune different situations.